# Отображения графика по координатам средствами текстового режима

Tags: c#

Для функции Y = f(X), вывести на экран значения Y для Х = 0, 0.25, 0.5, ... 19.75.
Получить на экране график функции средствами текстового режима. У меня получилось рассчитать значения Y, и вывести соответствующую таблицу. Но не понимаю как построить график, у меня получается так что он отображается зеркально, а не так как мне нужно, я так понимаю что нужно поставить знак '-' в строчке `y = (Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(x - 1, 2)) - 1);`, но тогда ничего не отображается в этом месте. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить?

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x, y; 

        Console.WriteLine("|   x   |   y   |");

        double maxY = Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(1 - 1, 2)) - 1;

        for (x = 0; x <= 4; x += 0.20)
        {

            if (x < 2)
            {
                y = (Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(x - 1, 2)) - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                y = -0.5 * Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(x - 3, 2));
            }

            Console.Write($"| {x,5:F2} | {y + 1,5:F2} |");

            PrintGraph(maxY, y);

            Console.WriteLine();
        } 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }  

    static void PrintGraph(double maxY, double y)
    {
        StringBuilder graphLine = new StringBuilder("          ");  
        int h = (int)((y + 1) * 10);

        if (h >= 0 && h < 10)
        {
            graphLine[9 - h] = '*'; 
        }

        Console.Write(graphLine);
    }
}
```

График который нужен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И тот который у меня

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]